# Shift location of printed matched result

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a list of some contacts on sheet1 which are matched with master list on sheet2 and matched contacts Email_ID is to be picked from master list. Results in the form of contact with Email_ID are to be printed on sheet3 starting from column H onwards. 
Program code works but results are printed starting from column A. It seems I am using offset property in a wrong way.

Samples of sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 are appended below.

[image: contacts to match]  [image: master list]

[image: matched contacts]

Program Code as follows.

```
 Sub GetEAddress()
    Dim c
    Dim Fin As Range
    Dim SearchRangeS1, SearchRangeS2
    Set SearchRangeS1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set SearchRangeS2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Sheet3.Cells.Clear
    Sheet3.Range("H1") = "Name"
    Sheet3.Range("I1") = "Email_ID"
     For Each c In SearchRangeS2
    Set Fin = Nothing
    Set Fin = SearchRangeS1.Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not Fin Is Nothing Then
        With Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Value = c
            .Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 8).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 8).Value
        End With
      End If
     Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing wrong column on sheet3 and your row number is not getting incremented.

Try this:

```
Sub GetEAddress()
    Dim c
    Dim Fin As Range
    Dim SearchRangeS1, SearchRangeS2
    Dim i As Integer  '<-- Newly added
    Set SearchRangeS1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set SearchRangeS2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Sheet3.Cells.Clear
    Sheet3.Range("H1") = "Name"
    Sheet3.Range("I1") = "Email_ID"
    i = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1    '<-- Newly added
    For Each c In SearchRangeS2
        Set Fin = Nothing
        Set Fin = SearchRangeS1.Find(c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Fin Is Nothing Then
            With Sheet3.Range("H" & i)  '<-- Changed here
                .Value = c
                .Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 8).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 8).Value
                i = i + 1  '<-- Newly added
            End With
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```